# Confused by failuer of CDialog::Create()

Tags: mfc, cdialog

```
ZTRACE_RUNTIME("Creating Processing Panel");
BOOL result = processingDlg.Create(IDD_PROCESSING);
if (FALSE == result)
{
    int lastErr = GetLastError();
    ZTRACE_RUNTIME("lastErr = %d", lastErr);    
}
```

This is a debug build.

Problems:

1. I can't step into `Create` using <kbd>F11</kbd>???
2. Result was set to `0`, so `GetLastError` was invoked, but that returned `0`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* Not posting sufficient information for anyone to diagnose your problem or help resolve it.

Comment: Try it on a statically built project.

Comment: Well if had a clue what information you needed other than that I provided, I would have done so.  If you want further information you should say what you need, not snipe at me.

Comment: As suggested above, (temporarily) change your project settings to use MFC as a statically linked library, rather than as shared (so you can debug it). Possible reasons: a) the `IDD_PROCESSING` identifier is invalid or cannot be found or the resource is not suitable, eg a child dialog, b) `Create()` is the method to create a modeless dialog box, is this what you wanted? If yes, how did you construct the `processingDlg` instance? Which constructor did you use? Check the [CDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class?view=msvc-170) documentation.

Comment: And I changed nothing and it started working again.